# Div background translucent, not contents?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a div with a translucent background, but fully opaque contents. Here's what I have:

```
#mydiv { 
 color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 900px;
 height: 140px;
 border: 0px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 background: #000000;
 opacity: .2;
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

Is there a way to do this with CSS?

Comment: See `rgba()` colors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/color_value

Comment: How different these answers are!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
```

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color) is some more information on `rgba()`.

Comment: That is really great, but I would argue that they should have stuck with an `a` between 0 and 255, for consistency

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS3 color property `rgba`.

```
background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

All children will have at most the same transparency as their parent. Meaning that if your div has an opacity of 0.2, their children's opacity of 1 will be equivalent to 0.2.

```
div1 opacity = 0.2
  div2 opacity = 1
    div3opacity = 0.5
```

Meaning :

```
div1 --> real opacity = 0.2 == 0.2
div2 --> real opacity = 0.2 * 1 == 0.2
div3 --> real opacity = 0.2 * 1 * 0.5 == 0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#mydiv { 
 color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 900px;
 height: 140px;
 border: 0px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 opacity: .2;
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The `opacity:.2` will cause the div and all its children to be translucent

Answer (score 0):

One hack to do this (besides the CSS3 rgba rules) is to create a solid colored png with only 10% opacity.  Use it as a `background-image`, example image below

X [image] X

(a 10% white png is above)